# Show hover text of internal links in exported HTML in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-ref

Is there a way to show hover text of internal links in exported HTML in org-mode? Sometime I would like to have a quick peek of the reference details of a `org-ref` citation link when reading the exported HTMLs of my notes.

Comment: Give the link text text-property `help-echo` with the text you want to show in a tooltip.

Comment: @Drew That works in org-mode buffer, but not in the exported HTML.

Comment: Sorry; I didn't read the question well. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to define your own cite export function like this and then set it on the cite link.

```
(defun my-html-cite-export (keys desc format)
  (mapconcat
    (lambda (key)
      (format "<a class='org-ref-reference' href=\"#%s\" title=\"%s\">%s</a>"
          key
          (org-ref-format-entry key)
          key))
    (org-ref-split-and-strip-string keys) ","))

(org-link-set-parameters "cite" :export #'my-html-cite-export)
```

This has some limitations, it only applies on cite links, and not the many other types of cite links, and it only supports html export. There isn't another way to do this at this time though.